# jQuery: how to get all stylesheet classes+ids into an array

Tags: jquery, css, class

i'm using a wysiwyg editor which has a .css applied - how can i get all its classes into a variable eg. allClasses = ['navi','main']?

thx

Answer (score 3):

Use the `[id]` or `[class]` selector. That selects all elements that have this attribute defined. Then just call `attr('id')` on them and fetch the id.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.allAttributes = function(attrName) {
        var selector = "[{attr}]".replace("{attr}", attrName);
        var attributes = $(selector, this).map(function() {
            return $(this).attr(attrName).split(' ');
        });
        attributes = $.unique(attributes);
        return attributes;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This is a jQuery plugin that does exactly that. Example usage:

```
var ids = $("body").allAttributes("id");
var classes = $("body").allAttributes("class");
```

Some notes:

The function is calling `split(' ')` because the `class` attribute can have multiple CSS classes separated by a string such as `"main navi footer"`. This separates them into separate items. `$.unique` is called on the array at the end because class names could have been repeated at multiple places and I'm guessing you don't want duplicates.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/G4Pwc/